# change edittext text color in older platform version

Tags: android, android-edittext, platform

I am using a dark background for my app. The text color of edittext is set as white. It is working fine in latest versions. But in older versions since the edittext itself is displaying as white color i am not able to see the entered text in edittext. how can i handle this?

Comment: check your style.xml may be it has define white color background to view.

Comment: i want to keep it as same in latest versions.just need to chnage the text color in older versions.is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make new `xml` file in **`res/drawable`** name it **rounded_edit_text** then paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#F9966B" />
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

In **`res/layout`** copy and past following code (code of `EditText`) :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtdoctor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
    android:ems="10" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this thing as it included in API level 1:

```
editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.your_color));
editText.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.id.your_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the background as color white in your style.xml. 
In older version it will also set as background color of editttext,dialog like views;
  please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16902350/1186689). 
It is about setting `android:windowBackground` and `android:colorBackground` . 
Hope it will help you.